# EF Unique property in entity - one context, multiple databases code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I have a specific scenario:

- one DbContext MyContext
- twoDatabases Db1 and Db2
- Entity MyEntity with properties a, b, and c

Context:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext(string connString) : base(connString)
    {

    }

    public virtual DbSet<MyEntity> MyDbSet { get; set; }
```

I apply migration in db1, it creates table MyEntity, with columns a,b,c.

Now with the same context i want to have MyEntity in db2 but only with columns a,b. What I do is:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    if(IsDb2)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().Ignore(x => x.PropertyC);
    }
}
```

But it results in error when adding a migration: The property PropertyC is not a declared property on type MyEntity.

Is what I'm trying to achieve even possible with EF? I'm using EF 6.

Many thanks in advance for clarifying this!

Comment: Could you provide context as to why this needs to be done?

Comment: Multiple databases with same tables but in some cases not all fields will be needed, so i dont want them in some of my databases. Which of them - will be decied during development thats why I want to manipulate this accoring to my needs.

Comment: Even if this was possible you shouldn't do it.Either create another context with another Entity that doesn't have the extra property or just ignore it if you don't want to use it